# Need help in understanding optimal algorithm that mentions parity sum ( finding one missing integer in a permutation )

Tags: algorithms

I need help in understand what is "parity sum" here and optimal solution with this parity sum. Also I am not getting how do we need $2$log$n$ bits for nearly optimal solution...

> Let $π$ be a permutation of $\{1,... ,n\}$. Further, let $π_{−1}$ be $π$ with one element missing. Paul shows Carole $π_{−1}[i]$ in increasing order $i$. Carole’s task is to determine the missing integer. Let us assume she has only a few—say $O($log $n)$—bits of memory. This starter puzzle has a simple solution: Carole stores
>   $$ s = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \Sigma_{j \leq i}  \ π_{−1}[j]$$
>
> which is the missing integer in the end. Each input integer entails one subtraction. The total number of bits stored is no more than $2$log$n$. This is nearly optimal because Carole needs at least log$n$ bits in the worst
>   case since she needs to output the missing integer. (In fact, there exists the following optimal algorithm for
>   Carole using log n bits. For each i, store the parity sum of the ith bits of all numbers seen thus far. The final
>   parity sum bits are the bits of the missing number.) A similar solution will work even if n is unknown, for
>   example by letting $n = max_{j≤i} π_{−1}[j]$ each time.

Thank you for help!

Comment: To store an integer smaller than $n$, we needs $\log n$ bits. You can think this in this way: If you have $k$ bits, each bit can be $0$ or $1$, then given a $k$-bits string, you can correspond it to an integer between $0$ and $2^k-1$. Therefore $2\log n$ is just number of bits needed to store an integer between $0$ and $n^2$.

Comment: @k99731 sure, makes sense. What about parity sum... What does it mean here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure the optimal solution out. I will illustrate it here. Choose $n=8$. I am not sure about other $n$, so you may have to work them out.

We have

```
000
001
010
011
100
101**
110
111
```

We will take $100$ away.

Parity sum of $i$th-digit$=$number of $1$ in $i$th digit $\mod 2$

In this case, there are three $1$ in the first bit (counted from the left). Then Parity sum of first digit is $1$.

After you calculated the sums for each digits, put them together you can have $100$.

EDIT: This is not a proof for the optimal solution. It is just an illustration.

Comment: I searched what is parity sum online and I could not find the right definition for this problem. Thanks for help

Comment: @LeoWon In fact I didn't too. But I shouldn't really say that in this problem, because I don't think that is a very popular term. Sorry about what I have said before edit.